# Raspbian .bin installing issue

Tags: linux, debian, driver, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspbian OS, and I need to install *.bin wi-fi driver (rt2870) on it.
Executing from root says "cannot execute binary file"
`sudo rt2870.bin` from root tells "Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")"
`sudo ./rt2870.bin` - the same.

I've made `chmod +x rt2870.bin`  before executing

What is the problem?

Searching tells me that I'm trying to install x64 program on x86, or x86 on ARM (RPi in my case) and that is impossible. But I already had it installed, but then I re-installed Raspbian and now I'm stuck with this problem.

Comment: May it be that you are supposed to copy the rt2870.bin into /lib/firmware instead of executing it?

Comment: @jewirth I've copied it to /lib/firmware (where I found various rtXXXX binaries), how do I install it to make wi-fi go? Last time I've just executed it and it was working ok. After re-installation it is not. The file is the same.

Comment: Oh, silly me. It is working now. Driver was ok, it wasn't a problem